# fedora 19: Unable to configure EPEL package repository

Tags: git, fedora, yum

I am trying to install private cloud using Eucalyptus 3.4 on 64 bit fedora 19.
One step in installation is to configure EPEL package Repository by firing following command.
**yum install http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software/eucalyptus/3.4/centos/6/x86_64/epel-release-6.noarch.rpm**
 This command fails to execute by trying to contact mirror site.
Help in this regard is appreciated.
output of the above command is

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
epel-release-6.noarch.rpm                                                                                |  14 kB  00:00:00       
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-DOyDVi/epel-release-6.noarch.rpm: epel-release-6-8.noarch  
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-DOyDVi/epel-release-6.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies    
--> Running transaction check  
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:6-8 will be installed  
--> Processing Conflict: epel-release-6-8.noarch conflicts fedora-release  
http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software//euca2ools/3.0/centos/19/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found  
Trying other mirror.  
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from euca2ools-release: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.  
       http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software//euca2ools/3.0/centos/19/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above issue by following instructions given in following post

http://www.geekdevs.com/2011/09/solved-fedora-release-conflicts-with-epel-release-5-4-noarch-on-fedora-15/